# Crashing after receiving SNMP-response with PySNMP library

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

Crashing after receiving SNMP-response with PySNMP library

Script crashed after receiving get-response

Used:
Windows 10
pysnmp 4.4.12
Python interpreter: 3.10

Here is my code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

iterator = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                  CommunityData('public', mpModel=1),
                  UdpTransportTarget(('172.19.6.41', 161)),
                  ContextData(),
                  ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0'))
                  )
print('start')

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)

if errorIndication:  # SNMP engine errors
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:  # SNMP agent errors
        print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1] if errorIndex else '?'))
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:  # SNMP response contents
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
print('end')
```

########################################################################################
I can see that in the wireshark SNMP-request sent and responded.
In terminal I see following crash:

tag:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe C:\Projects\pythonProject\OOO\SNMP_examples\PySNMP\04_get_snmp.py 
start
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dispatch.py", line 45, in runDispatcher
loop(timeout or self.getTimerResolution(),
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 214, in loop
poll_fun(timeout, map)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 157, in poll
read(obj)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 94, in read
obj.handle_error()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 90, in read
obj.handle_read_event()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 427, in handle_read_event
self.handle_read()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dgram\base.py", line 170, in handle_read
self._cbFun(self, transportAddress, incomingMessage)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\base.py", line 84, in _cbFun
self.__recvCallables[recvId](
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\entity\engine.py", line 151, in __receiveMessageCbFun
self.msgAndPduDsp.receiveMessage(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\proto\rfc3412.py", line 291, in receiveMessage
msgVersion = verdec.decodeMessageVersion(wholeMsg)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\proto\api\verdec.py", line 15, in decodeMessageVersion
seq, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 2003, in __call__
for asn1Object in streamingDecoder:
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1918, in __iter__
for asn1Object in self._singleItemDecoder(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1778, in __call__
for value in concreteDecoder.valueDecoder(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 654, in valueDecoder
for chunk in substrateFun(asn1Object, substrate, length, options):
TypeError: decodeMessageVersion.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Projects\pythonProject\OOO\SNMP_examples\PySNMP\04_get_snmp.py", line 19, in <module>
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\sync\cmdgen.py", line 113, in getCmd
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dispatch.py", line 50, in runDispatcher
raise PySnmpError('poll error: %s' % ';'.join(format_exception(*exc_info())))
pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: poll error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dispatch.py", line 45, in runDispatcher
loop(timeout or self.getTimerResolution(),
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 214, in loop
poll_fun(timeout, map)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 157, in poll
read(obj)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 94, in read
obj.handle_error()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 90, in read
obj.handle_read_event()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncore.py", line 427, in handle_read_event
self.handle_read()
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\asyncore\dgram\base.py", line 170, in handle_read
self._cbFun(self, transportAddress, incomingMessage)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\carrier\base.py", line 84, in _cbFun
self.__recvCallables[recvId](
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\entity\engine.py", line 151, in __receiveMessageCbFun
self.msgAndPduDsp.receiveMessage(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\proto\rfc3412.py", line 291, in receiveMessage
msgVersion = verdec.decodeMessageVersion(wholeMsg)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysnmp\proto\api\verdec.py", line 15, in decodeMessageVersion
seq, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 2003, in __call__
for asn1Object in streamingDecoder:
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1918, in __iter__
for asn1Object in self._singleItemDecoder(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1778, in __call__
for value in concreteDecoder.valueDecoder(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 654, in valueDecoder
for chunk in substrateFun(asn1Object, substrate, length, options): ;TypeError: decodeMessageVersion.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
caused by <class 'TypeError'>: decodeMessageVersion.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

#################################################################################
In case I commenting  `#ContextData(),`

Request isn't sent, but in terminal I can see start and end printed.

I tried to send SNMP request and receive response in the terminal.

I sent response and expected to get response in the terminal.

Comment: Please edit your question to make use of code blocks and quotation, the massive error log is hard to read just plain text, and it makes you're actual text/question stand out :)

Comment: Yes, you will not get help unless the crucial stack trace is legible.

Comment: https://github.com/pyasn1/pyasn1/issues/28

Comment: I transferred script  to the Linux and it works for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Expanded my comment above.

Your initial attempt on Windows somehow resolved the dependent `pyasn1` to an incompatible version 0.5.0. That's the classic cause of the crash and the call stack indicated that clearly.

Your last attempt on Linux worked, simply `pyasn1` version 0.5.1 was shipped and the incompatibility is gone.

But you should expect more issues once you switch to Python 3.12, as `asyncore` is gone then.

You might want to read [this announcement](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/429) to see what else you should know about PySNMP.